# Can't execute code snippets

Tags: c#, code-snippets

Trying to execute try/catch code snippet. I type try and have menu:

[image]

None in menu selected generates code, they print only what was selected. For example, if I select `CodeTryCatchFinallyStatement`, I have only this word in IDE:

[image]

I suppose it is not class, but what is this?

How to make system generate code snippets like:

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

Comment: Press double `Tab` key on menu `try`

Comment: Please check the [CodeTryCatchFinallyStatement **Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetrycatchfinallystatement(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Comment: Wat program do you use?

Answer (score 0):

This is because CodeTryCatchFinallyStatement is a class.
just press Tab on "try" and it will generate the statement for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `tab` to confirm your selected value.

If you have some existing code block try CTRL+K+S (Surround With)

[image]